# Materialized View - PCTFREE and PCTUSED

Tags: oracle, performance

I have some questions about optimizing materialized views (MVs):

In the following tutorial it is recommended to set PCTFREE and PCTUSED to 0 or 99:

> Note: If a materialized view is complete refreshed, then set it's
> PCTFREE to 0 and PCTUSED to 99 for maximum efficiency.

--> https://satya-dba.blogspot.com/2009/07/materialized-views-oracle.html

First question:

Is this recommendation correct? Should the two parameters PCTFREE 0 and PCTUSED 99 be set accordingly?

How is that exact procedure when the MV is updated?

The MV is created ( PCTFREE 0 and PCTUSED 99 are set accordingly):

```
 CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "SYSK85"."CMVF_01_SK85_BESTAND_2019" ("BRNR", "LEAT", "TLRTAL", "LEATSO", "STAND_DATUM", "VOAT", "AQEQ", "ELAT", "ELDT", "VSKN", "VTKZ", "ANZAHL")
 PCTFREE 0 PCTUSED 99
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
 NO INMEMORY 
 BUILD IMMEDIATE
 USING INDEX 
 REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
 ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
 AS (
 select BRNR, LEAT, TLRTAL, LEATSO, STAND_DATUM, VOAT, AQEQ, ELAT, ELDT, VSKN, VTKZ, count(*) as ANZAHL 
 from CVF_SK85_BESTAND_2019 GROUP BY BRNR, LEAT, TLRTAL, LEATSO, STAND_DATUM, VOAT, AQEQ, ELAT, ELDT, VSKN, VTKZ
);
```

Second question:

Should the Create of the MV be set the two parameters PCTFREE 0 and PCTUSED 99?

But what if the MV is updated?

```
EXEC DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('CMVF_01_SK85_BESTAND_2019', 'C', atomic_refresh=>FALSE);
```

Should the two parameters PCTFREE and PCTUSED be reset again explicitly after the update (so that the database can reorganize the data - if necessary)? Or is not that necessary?

Thank you very much

Kind regards

George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imporatant point is the *limitation* to the *complete refresh* of the `MV`.

Such `MV` are refreshed either by `truncate` and `insert` or `delete` + `insert`, so the *recommendation* boils down to a *trivial* statement that you should not reserve space for *future updates*  that would newer happen in complete refresh (`PCTFREE = 0`).

This will lead to a decrease of the size of the MV.

`PCTUSED` plays IMO *no role* in this scenario as there are no *subsequent inserts*.

Both parameters remain valid until they are explicitely changed with `ALTER TABLE`.

**Summary**

If you are unsure about the refresh strategy, I'd never touch those parameters.

If you know that you only make *full refressh*  **and**  you make a lot of *full tables scans* on the `MV` - you may see an *optimizing effect*. While doing normal `OLTP` index access and nested loops joins on the `MV` you'll hardly see a difference.

Comment: Thank you very much Marmite for your help. Then I will not customize the settings and allow to default